# If an ARMA(p,q) model works well on differenced time series, then what model would work on raw time series?

Tags: time-series, arima

I have an ARIMA(4,0,2) model that works well for 168-differenced data, that is, I fitted it to $Y_t-Y_{t-168}$.

Based on this, would it be a good idea to try to fit a Seasonal ARIMA(4,0,2)(0,1,0)[168] or a SARIMA(4,0,2)(0,1,1)[168]?

What would be a good way to decide the order of the polynomial in $B^{168}$ in front of the white noise terms?

Comment: I'm curious what type of business or natural time series has a 168 periodicity?

Comment: @Skander H. It’s hourly data of energy consumption with daily and weekly periodicity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is the obvious candidate, since it's implied by the differencing (i.e. if you difference that first SARIMA you get the initial ARIMA model - with a zero mean).

However, that doesn't mean that the model with more parameters won't be noticeably a better model -- there's to little information here to judge what the circumstances really are.

Comment: I just spotted a mangled phrase (I broke it during the initial edit), which was quite misleading. Now fixed.